# How can I transfer my java NetBeans project connected to SQL management server database to another computer?

Tags: java, sql-server, netbeans, desktop-application, transfer

Now I have a clinic management system I developed in NetBeans and the project is connected to the SQL server manager. Now I want to copy my project with its connection as a whole so it would work as a desktop application on the other laptop from an icon on the desktop rather than opening NetBeans and running the file. What are the procedures to take to transfer my project and the database and work as a desktop app?

Comment: One way is to use NetBeans to create an external runnable JAR file.  You have to install the database, create the database tables, and run the JAR file.

Comment: so you mean I should install sql server manager on the other laptop with the same table names and columns and the copy the JAR file to the other PC? what about the JDBC and the db connection in the code i think the path will be different

Comment: How are you connecting to the database?

Comment: I downloaded JDBC and connected via netbeans

Comment: Connection myconn= null; //To connect to database
     Statement mystat= null; //setting the query 
     ResultSet myres= null; //preservering the result after applying the query
     DefaultTableModel dm;
    
    
        String url= "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1;databaseName=ClinicManagment";
        String user = "sa";
        String password="";

Comment: You're connecting using the URI "localhost".  When you install the database on a different machine, it should be able to connect using the URI "localhost".

Comment: okay I'll give it a try and reply to you. If you have any resource I can refer to that would be great. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issued; after the project jar built, if you just copy the Jar file to others PCs, it won't work.... You have to copy also a the lib folder in the dist directory where you found the JAR file, it contains the libraries you used while programming

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).